# move value from al to si in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

In my .asm code, i take keyboard input from the user which is stored in al register, So how to move value from al to si. When i directly try

```
mov si, al
```

then this error shows up - invalid combination of upcode and operands.

Comment: ```si``` is a 16 bit register, ```al``` is an 8 bit register. You want ```movzx si, al```, ```movsx```, or otherwise deal with the difference, e.g. use the whole ```ax``` for input.

Comment: Which processor do you intend to run on. 386+ or a something earlier than that like 8086/80286